# How could I automatically read all of the directories and add all files that end in .js to discord collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

This is the code I currently have, how would adapt this to check each sub-directory:

```
const fs = require('fs')

module.exports = (client, Discord) =>{
    const command_files = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'))

    for(const file of command_files){
            const command = require(`../commands/${file}`);
            if(command.name) {
                client.commands.set(command.name, command);
            } else {
                continue
            }
         }
}
```

And this is the layout I have for the commands folder [the folder layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCjxU.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap the whole code into a function and use some recursion.

Please note that, when using recusion, a `depth` variable is a wise way to handle it

Something like this should do it:

```
const fs = require('fs')

module.exports = (client, Discord) =>{

    const depth = 3;
    const finder = (path, currentDepth = 0) => {

        if (currentDepth >= depth) {
            return; // Breaks here
        }

        const dirContent = fs.readdirSync(path);
        const command_files = dirContent.filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
        const folders = dirContent.filter(file => {
            const dirPath = path + file;
            // Exists + is a directory verification
            return fs.existsSync(dirPath) && fs.lstatSync(dirPath).isDirectory();
        );

        for(const file of command_files){
            const filePath = '../' + path + file;
            const command = require(filePath);
            if(command.name) {
                client.commands.set(command.name, command);
            } else {
                continue
            }
         }

         // Loops through folders
         folders.map((folder) => finder(path + folder + '/', currentDepth + 1));
    }

    finder('./commands/');
}
```